# I need some help on installing ubuntu 15.04 over windows 10

Tags: 15.04, windows-10

Ok, So i have Ubuntu 15.04 iso on my flash drive. And i have disabled fast boot and secure boot on my ASUS Q320LA. I keep restarting it and go onto the boot screen and select my USB, but then it just goes to windows normal start screening instead of running the ubntu iso. What am i doing wrong??

Comment: How did you put the ISO on to the flash drive? Try unetbootin to make the flash drive bootable. unetbootin is available here: http://unetbootin.github.io/

Comment: oh i just dropped the file onto the usb lol thanks

Comment: No problem - that's what I figured it was. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just copied the ISO to the USB drive. That isn't how it works. You need to actually "burn" the ISO, which essentially extracts it and copies the contents to the USB stick. I would recommend using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) to burn the ISO. It's a quick and easy-to-use program. There's also a portable version, so no need for an installation.